# Reload the Main Activity after every X minutes to Update RSS feed

Tags: android, rss, android-intent

i am developing an android app that fetches an RSS feed, now i want it to update itself after every X time ..i.e restart the activity , i tired using Alarm manager but no success . im new to android app. i dont know where to put the restart code in the mainactivity.
 i goggled and found this

COde:
    Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);

if reloading the activity is not a good choice for this work then how to update it in background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use ListView to display feeds, and to reload the list use method:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the activity is not a good idea.I think you should use a Service
See this project: http://code.google.com/p/android-rss

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use a different thread to load things in the background, loop that thread and create a timer. for every time limit reached, do the update code. there are many way to achieve this, by using your own thread, using message handler, or by using [asnycTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) . by this method, when you update the rss feed, it won't block the UI thread and your apps won't looks laggy.